# Why is selected value null in wpf listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have connected to a database using entity framework and put the make and model of cars into a listbox in the format: Make - Model.

When I select an item from the listbox I would like to get the ID of that object to use it in another query which will display full details of that specific car(row in database) in a textblock.

When I select an item from the listbox it throws back a null value at:

> int id = (int)ltbxAvailableCars.SelectedValue;

In XAML, I have specified:

> Listbox SelectedValuePath="ID"

Are there any obvious mistakes here that I'm just not seeing?

Thank you in advance.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    CarRentalDBEntities db = new CarRentalDBEntities();

    public enum CarType { All, Small, Medium, Large }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cbxCarType.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarType));
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CarType type;
        Enum.TryParse<CarType>(cbxCarType.SelectedValue.ToString(), out type);

        string carType = type.ToString();

        if (carType == "All")
        {
            ltbxAvailableCars.Items.Clear();
            var cars = from c in db.Cars
                       select new
                       {
                           c.ID,
                           c.Make,
                           c.Model,
                           c.Size
                       };

            foreach (var car in cars)
            {
                ltbxAvailableCars.Items.Add(car.Make + " - " + car.Model);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ltbxAvailableCars.Items.Clear();
            var cars = from c in db.Cars
                       where c.Size == carType
                       select new
                       {
                           c.ID,
                           c.Make,
                           c.Model,
                           c.Size
                       };

            foreach (var car in cars)
            {
                ltbxAvailableCars.Items.Add(car.Make + " - " + car.Model);
            }
        }  
    }

    private void ltbxAvailableCars_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int id = (int)ltbxAvailableCars.SelectedValue;

        CarRentalDBEntities db = new CarRentalDBEntities();

        var query = from c in db.Cars
                    where c.ID == id
                    select new
                    {
                        c.ID,
                        c.Make,
                        c.Model,
                        c.Size
                    };

        tblkSelectedCarDetails.Text = query.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: `SelectedValue` can be used(not null) when listbox filled using `.DataSource`, `DisplayMemeber` and `ValueMember` properies. In your case listbox filled with manually added items. Try using `SelectedItem` property, or use `DataSource` for listbox items

Comment: Hi thank you, the SelectedItem returns the string of the list item so I will try and work that into the query as opposed to the ID number. I believe you can't use DataSource on a listbox in a wpf application. Considering that you mentioned datasource, would you it would be a more advisable strategy to store the data from database into an ObservableCollection and work with that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is approach for your case. But on my opinion mentioned by you databinding with `ObservableCollection` seems more elegantly and even easily
Create class for keeping needed values in the Listbox items

```
public class Car
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Make { get; set; }
    public String Model { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return String.Format("{0} - {1}", this.Make, this.Model);
    }
}
```

`ToString` will be override and return string which you want be shown in the listbox.
ListBox call `.ToString()` method of the item for displayed text

Then in the LINQ query create instances of that class and add them to the listbox

```
ltbxAvailableCars.Items.Clear();
var cars = from c in db.Cars
           where c.Size == carType
           select new Car
           {
               ID = c.ID,
               Make = c.Make,
               Model = c.Model
           };

foreach (Car car in cars)
{
    ltbxAvailableCars.Items.Add(car);
}
```

And use it in the `SelectionChanged` event handler

```
private void ltbxAvailableCars_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Car temp = (Car)ltbxAvailableCars.SelectedItem;
    Int32 id = temp.ID
    CarRentalDBEntities db = new CarRentalDBEntities();

    var query = from c in db.Cars
                where c.ID == id
                select new
                {
                    c.ID,
                    c.Make,
                    c.Model,
                    c.Size
                };

    tblkSelectedCarDetails.Text = query.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Just a small bit of fine tuning for the textblock. Thank you Fabio!

Answer (score 0):

Pertinent to your case, you may try to use `e.AddedItems` (args passed to your method `ltbxAvailableCars_SelectionChanged`) and extract the value from it, as detailed in MSDN online: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
Hope this may help. Best regards,

Comment: Hi, similar to above comment I believe your suggestion would give me the string of the selected item as would the suggestion above using SelectedItem, maybe I'm wrong? I will try to break up the string data in selected item and use that for the query.

Comment: In simple words: argument e.AddedItems in the SelectionChanged handle event of the ListBox refers to all selected items (it can be one, many or none), so extract the data from that arg (refer to MSDN sample, it's rather straightforward). Best regards,